# Typescript, javascript, better way of writing this

Tags: typescript

This will be an easy question for someone, typescript doesn't like the below syntax, how do I rewrite it using jQuery 'on'?

```
    var funcA= "FuncA('" +id+ "'," +max+ ");";
    $textbox[0].onkeyup = new Function(funcA));
```

I could possibly pass id and max in a closure but I'd like to know how to use 'Function' with the jQuery 'on' function

It would also be useful to know if it's possible to specify a region in typescript as ignorable, to be able to say just treat this block as valid javascript

Thanks

Comment: The syntax is valid except the last double parenthesis "))". Remove one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

How did you ever come up with this? Every time you realize you are writing a code to a string, you know you are doing it wrong. The `eval` function and the `Function` constructor should be forgotten.

```
$textbox[0].onkeyup = function () { FuncA(id, max); }; // Solution 1
$textbox[0].onkeyup = FuncA.bind(null, id, max); // Solution 2

// Using jQuery
$($textbox[0]).keyup(FuncA.bind(null, id, max));
```

Comment: Legacy code. To be fair I did say "I could possibly pass id and max in a closure but I'd like to know how to use 'Function' with the jQuery 'on' function". Are you saying there are no circumstances in which you should ever use 'Function'

Comment: For an application which allows users to enter JavaScript themselves to run, then `new Function(userCode)` would probably be better than an `eval`, but that's a pretty rare use-case, and even then there would probably be better ways to do it, such as running the user code in a different window.

Answer (score 0):

**try this :**

```
    $textbox[0].keyup(function(){FuncA(id,max);});
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `.on` function. It should compile fine:

```
$textbox.on('keyup',()=> FuncA(id,max));
```